# Less.js: Compiler caching struggles

Tags: less, precompile

TLDR version:

Is there a way to cache a stateless LESS compilation result per LESS file? We have large LESS utils (e.g. from libraries) that are reused by many pages, but compiling them (in particular, the regex parsing) seems rather slow. `less.Parser` does produce an abstract syntax tree result, but that result doesn't seem stateless (see e.g. `less.Ruleset.evalImports`) so it doesn't seem suitable for caching for this purpose.

LONG VERSION:

I'm looking for some pointers about optimizing LESS server-side preprocessing at scale. We have an application built from many modules, each of which contributes some styles in the form of CSS, and also modules which provide LESS commons utilities like mixins and various variables. The application also exposes many endpoints, each of which pulls in a mixture of these dependencies.

For performance, we want to precompile and cache the styles for each endpoint, but here it collides with what seems to be LESS's fundamental design. In particular, LESS compilation feels *stateful*, in the sense that the same `@import` in different locations in different files produces different results (from a compiler-output point of view). This makes compiler caching hard, since there's no real way to make sure each LESS file is parsed once and done forever (i.e. each endpoint needs to reparse a LESS utils file for use in its own styles, and each module that wants to define its own styles also needs to do the same).

Possible approaches considered so far:

1. I've looked a little into caching the AST for each file during compilation (i.e. the output of less.Parser) but it seems futile, since the AST itself seems stateful (see e.g. less.Ruleset.evalImports). This is unfortunate since it seems that the parsing stage of the LESS compilation is by far the slowest portion (and can add about 20 minutes to an ~2 minute server startup time with precompilation on).
2. Also looked into injecting something other than an `@import (reference)` or the equivalent when compiling scripts. In particular, if I can convert the imports into the explicit state (set of current defined mixins/variables/etc.) from a previous compilation, I could try to inject those manually into the parsing process. Unfortunately this feels like it involves very deep hacking of less.js code, which I'd like to avoid.
3. Compile in the context of an endpoint (i.e. perform one giant LESS compilation for an endpoint's style dependencies). This instead bounds compilation time to (size of utils) * (# of endpoints), but doesn't help as much as it could when the number of endpoints is also very large. It also puts all the compilation into a single context, allowing for the unexpected cross-module state interactions produced by subtle ordering changes.
4. Topological sort everything and compile everything in one LESS compilation.  This makes sure each file only needs to be traversed once, but craps all over the global namespace.

In essence, the compilation time feels bounded by (size of LESS utils) * (# of LESS compilation events). Minimizing statefulness leans toward more compilation events, but explodes compilation time. Minimizing compilation events improves performance, but sacrifices state independence.

Caching a stateless compilation result (e.g. like a precompiled header file for gcc) would break the performance barrier and achieve the optimum result, but I'm not sure how this can be done in current less.js code. Does anyone have any pointers/info in this regard?

Comment: Did you actually measure parsing/generation timing ratio? Assuming that, according to various tests, for an average Less source code, the parsing stage is not slower than CSS generation stage (actually it's ~50%/50% for a primitive code (nesting + variables) and ~30%(parsing)/70%(toCSS) for a advanced code (heavy use of mixins/extends)), in your case each module CSS should be very small and use very little of the core-library for such optimizations to shave a significant amount of time. So maybe it's time to optimize Less code itself (more modular core and only required imports in modules)?

Comment: Additionally the main question is why to compile on server start-up rather than on module code changes? I can imagine various reasons for the "clean" compilation at start-up of course, but considering the problem itself (20min? it's equal to compiling >1200 Bootstrap themes even on a slow server) this does not sound like something you want to use often in the first place. (i.e. time to rethink the development workflow?)

Comment: Speaking of approaches. 1 & 2 do not sound realistic at all (roughly speaking, it's almost equal to writing your own compiler from scratch).
3 & 4: if modules are not supposed to affect each other and each one uses the same values for global variables of the core (i.e. the state of the shared code is indeed the same), it's not a problem to isolate each module when compiling everything at once (see for example [#2442](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442)).

Comment: Also, the mention of `@import (reference)` (sounds like it's always used) makes me suspicious about the structure of sources again. Normally for a proper written library you rarely need `(reference)` Ideally never at all, mixin (that should always be parametric) and variable set imports don't need any `(reference)`, and files with CSS rulesets that are not supposed to appear in the output should not be imported at all.

Comment: I.e.  `(reference)` itself has no significant impact on the performance of course, but takes it back to my first comment about possible need for modules/library refactoring (e.g. it should not be like "import *everything* then pick one or two mixins or styles out of that everything").